# Clean up corona cases database from wide-format to plottable using pandas python

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm making a jupyter notebook for accessing and plotting number of confirmed cases of corona.  You can access my notebook here: [https://gitlab.com/knjakob-blomquist/corona-data-analysis/](https://gitlab.com/knjakob-blomquist/corona-data-analysis) or clone it via:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:knjakob-blomquist/corona-data-analysis.git
```

The data is downloaded as a wide format csv-file, and imported to a pandas DataFrame as is, so that there are columns for provinces, regions/countries, Lat-, Long-coordinates, individual columns for cumulative sum confirmed case for each province each day (dates are strings) for each province/country. Se figure via link here [corona_database_wideformat.png](https://gitlab.com/knjakob-blomquist/corona-data-analysis/-/blob/master/corona_database_wide_format.png).

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to clean the data for plotting / apply curve fit to the data than the way I did here (for example using pd.melt or pd.wide_to_short or something). I feel that there should be some standard way but I can't seem to find it:

```
# load libraries and set plot style 
%pylab inline
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Download daily updates of corona confirmed cases from
# https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases
import requests
url = 'https://data.humdata.org/hxlproxy/api/data-preview.csv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCSSEGISandData%2FCOVID-19%2Fmaster%2Fcsse_covid_19_data%2Fcsse_covid_19_time_series%2Ftime_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv&filename=time_series_2019-ncov-Confirmed.csv'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

with open('corona_data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# Import the data from csv file into a pandas DataFrame
# and do initial processing
df = pd.read_csv('corona_data.csv')

# remove some columns as I'm only interested in total 
# per each country
df = df.drop(columns=['Province/State', 'Lat','Long'])

# group and sum all data into individual countries from their provinces
df = df.groupby('Country/Region').sum()

# invert the table so that dates become index
df = df.stack().unstack(0)

# process the date format from date strings
# add a column for dates
df['date'] = df.index

# string -> datetime format and add to day column
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d', infer_datetime_format=True)

# make 21 st of March into day 0
df['day'] = df['day'] - df['day'][0]
df.day = (df['day']).dt.days + 1
```

With the code above I will get the following table see figure in link: [corona_database_cleaned.png](https://gitlab.com/knjakob-blomquist/corona-data-analysis/-/blob/master/corona_database_cleaned.png)
And with that format I can perform curve fits etc. 
Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Looks fine to me. Note that you can replace `df = df.stack().unstack(0)` with `df = df.T` ;)

Comment: @IMCoins OP has required output, just wants suggestions for improvement

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Thank you! I guess I just somehow thought there was some magic function that I didn't know since this format (wide with dates in each column) seem to be common. I just could not figure out a "simple" way to plot and analyze this data.